# Perform actions on multiple objects (e.g text boxes) on a form

Tags: vb.net

This has been asked before I'm sure but I can't find a straight answer. Yonks ago in vb.net, you used to be able to create an array of objects on a form and use loops to perform actions on them. This was removed I believe after vb6?. In my example I have say 40 text boxes on a form all with same name plus a numeric suffix i.e txtProductName1, txtProductName2.. etc. So say I want to put an empty "" value in all of them (to clear them), I want to be able to do that without having 40 lines of code addressing each one individually. Can someone please suggest a solution.

Dim boxname As String

```
    For i = 1 To 40

        boxname = "txtProductName" & i.ToString
        Dim box1 As TextBox = DirectCast(TabControl2.Controls(boxname), TextBox)
        box1.Text = ""

    Next
```

Comment: Try with `For Each txtbox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, won't this go through all the text boxes on the form though? I only want to action certain ones.

Comment: Yeah it would go through them all. You could test each one's name as you go, or change the linq to filter by name.

Comment: Like this `For Each txtbox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith("TextBox"))`

Comment: Ahh coolio, that works a treat, thanks :-)